# Layout_weight to get 2 equal height layouts

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm currently modifying an xml layout, and I want to group all of the views into 2 sections, each half of the height available. The layout looks something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>   

    ...Lots of stuff...

</LinearLayout>
```

What I've done is to wrap each "half" of the views in a linear layout, and assign a weight to each.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>  

    <!-- Top half -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        ... stuff and things ...

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Bottom half -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        ... things and stuff ...

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I can't figure out why this doesn't give me 2 equal panes. The lower one seems to take up 90% of the available space. I've tried adding  (android:weightSum="2") to the container layout, but to no avail. None of these layouts have IDs, so the code behind shouldn't be able to modify them. Any idea what is going on here? Are the child views able to modify their "half" containers so that they wouldn't appear equal?

Comment: Your layout file seems alright. What the contents you are adding? Are there any images?

Comment: There's a whooolllle lotta stuff. There are images used for button icons and backgrounds, but they are realtively insignificant compared to the layout size. It looks like I'm just going to have to start fresh and start moving content over to the new layout piece by piece.

Answer (score 0):

This link may be of some use to you:

http://www.chess-ix.com/blog/the-use-of-layout_weight-with-android-layouts/

What you are doing seem to be correct, but probably the content in your Linearlayouts may be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding a weightSum to the parent LinearLayout, like so:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="2">  

    <!-- Top half -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        ... stuff and things ...

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Bottom half -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        ... things and stuff ...

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, I change layout_height of the children: you won't need fill_parent for the child LinearLayouts since the parent has that property already.